# Find vectors describing two interconnected pyramids in Euclidean space

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, matrix, vector-calculus, quaternions

I need the help of competent linear algebra specialists in Mathematica.

In the Euclidean space, two tetrahedrons are turned at different angles. Their vertices coincide with the beginning of the base coordinate system at the point (0,0,0). The coordinates of the remaining vertices are described by a triple of 3-dimensional vectors corresponding to each tetrahedron:

$W_{11},W_{12},W_{13}$ - for first tetrahedron;

$V_{21},V_{22},V_{23}$ - for second tetrahedron, **we need to find this vectors**;

The coordinates of the vectors for the first tetrahedron are known. It is necessary to find the coordinates of the remaining three vectors for the second tetrahedron. In this case, two conditions must be met:

1. Scalar product $W_{1j} \cdot W_{1j}$, $W_{2j} \cdot W_{2j}$ and $W_{3j} \cdot W_{3j}$, where $j=1,2,3$ of two corresponding vectors taken for the first and second tetrahedrons should be the $cos(\alpha)$.
2. Scalar product of two adjacent vectors for the second tetrahedron should be $cos(\beta)$.

In the form of equations, these conditions can be written as:

\begin{cases}
W_{11} \cdot V_{21} = \cos(\alpha) \\ W_{12} \cdot V_{22} = \cos(\alpha) \\ W_{13} \cdot V_{23} = \cos(\alpha) \\ V_{21} \cdot V_{22} = \cos(\beta) \\ V_{22} \cdot V_{23} = \cos(\beta) \\ V_{21} \cdot V_{23} = \cos(\beta)
\end{cases}

I can’t solve this system of equations directly and find the vectors I need, and I'm not sure if this is possible at all using the vector-matrix apparatus?

Numerically, this problem was also not solved in Mathematica; apparently, too complex equations are obtained. For this, I added unit length conditions for the vectors of the second tetrahedron to the equations.

```
In[5]:= pars = {Subscript[\[Alpha], 2] = 95*Pi/180, 
   Subscript[\[Alpha], 3] = 95*Pi/180, 
   Subscript[w, 1] = {0.2, 0.8, 0.3}, 
   Subscript[w, 2] = {0.4, 0.9, 0.1}, 
   Subscript[w, 3] = {0.2, 0.25, 0.38}, 
   Subscript[v, 1] = {Subscript[v, 11], Subscript[v, 12], 
     Subscript[v, 13]}, 
   Subscript[v, 2] = {Subscript[v, 21], Subscript[v, 22], 
     Subscript[v, 23]}, 
   Subscript[v, 3] = {Subscript[v, 31], Subscript[v, 32], 
     Subscript[v, 33]}};
}

NSolve[{Dot[Subscript[w, 1], Subscript[v, 1]] == 
   Cos[Subscript[\[Alpha], 2]], 
  Dot[Subscript[w, 2], Subscript[v, 2]] == 
   Cos[Subscript[\[Alpha], 2]], 
  Dot[Subscript[w, 3], Subscript[v, 3]] == 
   Cos[Subscript[\[Alpha], 2]], 
  Dot[Subscript[v, 1], Subscript[v, 2]] == 
   Cos[Subscript[\[Alpha], 3]], 
  Dot[Subscript[v, 2], Subscript[v, 3]] == 
   Cos[Subscript[\[Alpha], 3]], 
  Dot[Subscript[v, 1], Subscript[v, 3]] == 
   Cos[Subscript[\[Alpha], 3]], Norm[{Subscript[v, 1]}, 2] == 1, 
  Norm[{Subscript[v, 2]}, 2] == 1, 
  Norm[{Subscript[v, 3]}, 2] == 1}, {Subscript[v, 11], 
  Subscript[v, 12], Subscript[v, 13], Subscript[v, 21], 
  Subscript[v, 22], Subscript[v, 23], Subscript[v, 31], 
  Subscript[v, 32], Subscript[v, 33]}]
```

Comment: _Mathematica_ cannot solve this because she assumes that `Subscript[v, ...]` were all scalars and `Dot` is undefined for scalars. Moreover, do you really mean "pyramid" or rather "tetrahedron"? I am really confused by sentences like these "In the Euclidean space, two pyramids are turned at different angles. Their vertices coincide with the beginning of the base coordinate system at the point (0,0,0)." So all vertices are equal to (0,0,0)? Does not make sense. Please describe your problem more concisely and, if possible, provide an example.

Comment: I meant the tetrahedron, or the regular triangular pyramid

Comment: You can _edit_ your post to make that clear to the reader who stumbles upon this for the first time.

Comment: There do not appear to be real-valued solutions to the system. Me, I'm partial to tetrahedra in C^3/R^3. Are you certain you cannot use one such?

Comment: By the way, if you discard the second angle cosine, and instead set angles of pairwise "v" edges equal to corresponding angles of their "w" edge-pair counterparts, you do then get a bunch of real-valued solutions.

Comment: According to some reports, there should be 8 solutions. The cosines of the angles can be any, and equal, and different. In general, real solutions must exist for different cosines of angles. The fact is that I asked the initial vectors randomly and they turned out to be completely not unique, it is possible that this is the reason for the imaginary-valued solutions.

Comment: Numerically, I was abled to solve this problem in a very narrow range of initial parameters. My hope is a classic vector-matrix mathematical apparatus. I'm afraid if I have to turn to group theory? I am interested in the following: is it possible to get at least some analytical solution to this problem? Could you help me?

Comment: I do not offhand see a linear algebra approach here. Every method of turning into eqations seems to give quadratics. And for symbolic "w" vectors obtaining analytic solutions does not appear to be tractable.

Comment: And there are effective (in the sense of computation speed) numerical methods so that they can be applied in real time? Maybe you should pay attention to the Duran-Kerner method, Newton-Raphson with a bisector, etc.?